# Has anyone use mapred.job.tracker=local in hadoop streaming job?

Tags: hadoop, streaming, local

in last weeks, we use hadoop streaming to calculate some reports everyday. Recently we made a change to our program, if the input size is smaller than 10MB, we will set mapred.job.tracker=local in the JobConf, then the job will run locally.

But last night, many jobs failed, with status 3 returned by runningJob.getJobState().
I don't know why, and there is nothing in the stderr.

I can google nothing related about this question. So I'm wondering if I should use mapred.job.tracker=local in production mode? Maybe it's just a debug solution in developing supplied by hadoop.

Has anyone know something about it? Anything, Any infomation, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe setting `mapred.job.tracker=local` has nothing to do with your error as `local` is the default value. 
This config parameter defines the host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs at. If it is set to be "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map and reduce task.

Refer [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.0/mapred-default.html).

Comment: thanks. Because of the situation can not be replayed, I I will check it carefully next time it appears.